# How do I pass the ID of a Gridview to the XML WriteString method

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, gridview

I am using a GridView (Insert/Edit/Delete) in a submission form (textbox & dropdown controls) which renders data to an XML file. I am able to Edit/insert/Delete to the XML file via the GridView and the form controls tags also successfully copy the data entered over to the XML upon clicking the submit problem. My problem is that when the submit button is clicked, the data from the Gridview is erased, thus leaving only the data submitted from the form control tags.

The following is the code (button event handler) am using to write the data submitted via the form control tag:

```
Public Sub Write_XML(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim textWriter As New XmlTextWriter(Server.MapPath("xml/PersonDataVI.xml"), Nothing)
        textWriter.Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented
        'Start New Document
        textWriter.WriteStartDocument()
        'Write a Comment
        textWriter.WriteComment("This is a comment")
        'Insert Start Element -root element node
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("PersonalData")

        'write the child element
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("products")

        'write the child element
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("product")

        'save the data for the Grid
        Dim productID As String = DirectCast(gvProductNumber.FooterRow.FindControl("txtProductIDInsert"), 

TextBox).Text
        Dim productNumber As String = DirectCast(gvProductNumber.FooterRow.FindControl

("txtProductNumberInsert"), TextBox).Text
        BindGridView()
        Dim dtXMLInsert As DataTable = DirectCast(gvProductNumber.DataSource, DataTable)
        Dim dsgvProductNumber As New DataSet()
        dsgvProductNumber.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/PersonDataVI.xml"))
        Dim drInsert As DataRow = dsgvProductNumber.Tables("product").NewRow()
        drInsert("productID") = productID
        drInsert("productNumber") = productNumber
        Dim drParent As DataRow = dsgvProductNumber.Tables("products").Rows(0)
        drInsert.SetParentRow(drParent)
        dsgvProductNumber.Tables("product").Rows.Add(drInsert)
        dsgvProductNumber.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/PersonDataVI.xml"))
        BindGridView()

        textWriter.WriteEndElement()
        textWriter.WriteEndElement()

        'write the child element
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("customers")

        'write the child element
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("customer")

        'Write LastName Element and Data
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("LastName", "")
        textWriter.WriteString(txtLastName.Text)
        textWriter.WriteEndElement()

        'Write FirstName Element and Data
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("FirstName", "")
        textWriter.WriteString(txtFirstName.Text)
        textWriter.WriteEndElement()

        'Write Address Element and Data
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("Address", "")
        textWriter.WriteString(txtAddress.Text)
        textWriter.WriteEndElement()

        'Write City Element and Data
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("City", "")
        textWriter.WriteString(txtCity.Text)
        textWriter.WriteEndElement()

        'Write State Element and Data
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("State", "")
        textWriter.WriteString(txtState.Text)
        textWriter.WriteEndElement()

        'Write ZipCode Elment and Data
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("ZipCode", "")
        textWriter.WriteString(txtZipCode.Text)
        textWriter.WriteEndElement()

        'End Everything
        textWriter.WriteEndDocument()

        'Clean up
        textWriter.Flush()
        textWriter.Close()

        'Display the XML Document
        Response.Redirect(Server.MapPath("xml/PersonDataVI.xml"))
    End Sub
```

...the code works well for copying the data that is entered via the form control tags into the xml file. My question is, how do I get the Data from the Gridview to stay within the XML file when the button is clicked. As advised from a previous post, (please comments in my code snippet for saving Gridview data) I  added a new dataTable and added some columns to it, and filled it with some rows of data and I added it to the button event handler. However, now I'm getting an error that the "xml file is in use by another application." My xml file now just comes back blank. Could you please take a look at the snippet I provided above and render some guidence as to what I'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here - 1. Each time you are saving the xml, you are overwriting the xml file, thus previous data is lost, 2. After opening and saving xml file with xmltextwriter, it takes a little time to free the file, you can try after a pause to open it.
I would prefer using xdocument. Please check this post:[Writing XML to a file without overwriting previous data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486435/writing-xml-to-a-file-without-overwriting-previous-data).

**EDIT:** You can achieve desired result in the following way:

```
Public Sub Write_XML(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    'You have saved xml, now want to add data thorugh text boxes

    Dim dsgvPersonalData As New DataSet()
    dsgvPersonalData.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/PersonDataVI.xml"))

    'Add new Product
    Dim drNewProduct As DataRow = dsgvPersonalData.Tables("products").NewRow()
    Dim productID As String = DirectCast(gvProductNumber.FooterRow.FindControl("txtProductIDInsert"), TextBox).Text
    Dim productNumber As String = DirectCast(gvProductNumber.FooterRow.FindControl("txtProductNumberInsert"), TextBox).Text
    drNewProduct("productID") = productID
    drNewProduct("productID") = productNumber
    dsgvPersonalData.Tables("products").Rows.Add(drNewProduct)

    'Add new Customer
    Dim drNewCustomer As DataRow = dsgvPersonalData.Tables("customesr").NewRow()
    drNewProduct("LastName") = txtLastName.Text
    drNewProduct("FirstName") = txtFirstName.Text
    drNewProduct("Address") = txtAddress.Text
    drNewProduct("City") = txtCity.Text
    drNewProduct("State") = txtState.Text
    drNewProduct("ZipCode") = txtZipCode.Text
    dsgvPersonalData.Tables("customerx").Rows.Add(drNewProduct)

    'Save the xml
    dsgvPersonalData.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/PersonDataVI.xml"))

    'databinding is easy here
    gvProductNumber.DataSource = dsgvPersonalData.Tables("products")
    gvProductNumber.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: I actually want the xml file to populate with new data each time the form is used/ (submitted via the button click). Upon clicking the submit button, the XML file is currently populated with the Data inputted via the textbox controls only; I'm trying to figure out how to keep the Grid data in there as well. In other words re-write the grid data to the xml file when the submit button is clicked. Any other suggestions?

Comment: ...cont. ...So each time the submit button is clicked, I want to re-write the data from the gridview to the xml file along with the data submitted from the Text-box controls. Thus far, the data from the gridview is over-written with the data submitted from the textbox controls.

Comment: My understanding is, You have two child nodes in the root, Products and Customers. Products node is tied to the GridView. Now you want to add new Product through the text boxes and want to update the grid with this data. you are adding Customer also, but not binding to any gridview. Am I correct?

Comment: Edited answer will help to do above.

Comment: Partially correct, yes Products is tied to the gridview, but new products are added via the gridview only. Customer info is added via the textboxes only. No grid is being used for the customer info. I hope that clear things. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Yes, products are added through the text boxes in Gridview footer. Did you try the code?

Comment: Attention afzalulh ...yes, I tried the code provided;  I re-placed the section of code I was using to create the new dataTable with what you provided, I got the same error,  However, when I place the code you provided after the section of code that writes the data from the textboxes via the "WriteStartElement" meathod, (this is all done in the button-event handler) the xml file does populate with the products table but still no data.  Could you please check out my repost - How do I pass the ID of a Gridview to the XML WriteString method -part 2 -? There I will post both attempts I've made.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35704/discussion-between-user1724708-and-afzalulh)