# Overwriting feed in feed file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, rss, feed

I have a news website that has rss.

when I write first News in rss file. It work fine.

```
XmlWriter atomWriter = XmlWriter.Create(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\NewsFeed\NewsFeed.xml"));
Atom10FeedFormatter atomformatter = new Atom10FeedFormatter(Newsfeed);
atomformatter.WriteTo(atomWriter);

XmlWriter NewsRssWriter = XmlWriter.Create(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\NewsFeed\NewsFeed.xml"));

Rss20FeedFormatter rssformatter = new Rss20FeedFormatter(Newsfeed);
rssformatter.WriteTo(NewsRssWriter);
NewsRssWriter.Close();
```

but when I enter second news, this was overwrite on first news data.

I know reason. this is becuase belove code:

```
XmlWriter atomWriter = XmlWriter.Create(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\NewsFeed\NewsFeed.xml"));
```

but don't know how to solve this case. Rss20FeedFormatter Class and Atom10FeedFormatter Class both get parameter of XmlWriter Class type.

I Thanks anyOne that guide me ;)

Comment: Here is the previous soultion provided in [S0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486435/writing-xml-to-a-file-without-overwriting-previous-data).

Comment: That 's right. thanks alot :) I must search more. Thanks