# Writing in an XML file in c# (overwrite )

Tags: c#, xml

In my mini aplication I have a page with 3 textboxes where I can put some strings . I want those to be saved in am XML file. My problem is that every time I introduce a new set of data it get put over the existing one . 
This is my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            DateTime start, end;
            DateTime.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out start);
            DateTime.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, out end);
            float suma = 0.0f;
            float.TryParse(TextBox3.Text, out suma);
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("c:/users/ideapad/documents/visual studio 2013/Projects/XmlReader/XmlReader/rezervari.xml", settings))
            {
                writer.WriteStartDocument();
                writer.WriteStartElement("Rezervari");

                writer.WriteStartElement("Rezervare");
                writer.WriteElementString("ID", ID);
                writer.WriteElementString("start", start.ToShortDateString());
                writer.WriteElementString("end", end.ToShortDateString());
                writer.WriteElementString("suma", suma.ToString());
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndDocument();
                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();
            }

        }
```

how can I keep what I have and add next to it ? (I see no method load or something)

Comment: Of course you are overwriting your existing one, since you are just rewriting the whole xml.
You could just load the document via XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath); And start adding stuff.

Comment: well yes but how do I just open the XML or load it there is no method like that :| http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Not with `XmlTextWriter`, no. But `XDocument.Load` will do it... why are you using the writer API directly at all? There are cases where you need such low level APIs for streaming huge documents - but it sounds unlikely that that's the case here.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486435/writing-xml-to-a-file-without-overwriting-previous-data

Comment: assignment... XmlWriter/XmlTextWriter/XmlDocument/XmlNode/XmlNodeList are all i can use

Comment: Does your instructor allow you to have others do your homework?

Comment: My instructor allows me to search the internet for the Load function i need to not overwrite or recreate the Xml file :D that is for sure since he didn't bothered to tell me more than put that in an xml file and then take it out !

Answer (score 2):

I would use `LINQ to XML` for that. Here are the steps for appending a new element:

1. Load the XML file using [`XDocument.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. Create a new `XElement` using [`XElement` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. Add new element to the `Root` using [`XDocument.Root.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354061(v=vs.110).aspx) method.
4. Save the document using [`XDocument.Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.save(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I sadly am not allowed with anything more advanced than XmlWriter/XmlTextWriter/XmlDocument/XmlNode/XmlNodeList

Answer (score 2):

I have tweaked your code as below. This should solve your problem.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        DateTime start, end;
        DateTime.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out start);
        DateTime.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out end);
        float suma = 0.0f;
        float.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out suma);
        //Added this new line. Boolean parameter (true) here means append to existing content. 
        using (var stream = new StreamWriter("c:/users/ideapad/documents/visual studio 2013/Projects/XmlReader/XmlReader/rezervari.xml", true))
        {
            //Changed this line
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
            {
                writer.WriteStartDocument();
                writer.WriteStartElement("Rezervari");

                writer.WriteStartElement("Rezervare");
                writer.WriteElementString("ID", ID);
                writer.WriteElementString("start", start.ToShortDateString());
                writer.WriteElementString("end", end.ToShortDateString());
                writer.WriteElementString("suma", suma.ToString());
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndDocument();
                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Um, won't this just leave you with an non-well-formed XML document with more than one root node?

Comment: yes, yes it will :D but at least you can see more stuff!